# images not loaded when using fast polymer app loading

Tags: html, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying the app https://gist.github.com/ebidel/1ba71473d687d0567bd3 to load a screen loader until the app is loaded but all my images not loaded properly or not at all , and some styles are mess "styles of polymer elements" 
I think this is because the loading just after the html imports in line https://gist.github.com/ebidel/1ba71473d687d0567bd3#file-app-js-L37 . 
if it's true how to work around and if it's some thing else I appreciate your help

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing some actual code how you are using it.

Comment: I tried to submit some, but I don't know what to show, all I added to my code is exactly what is in the Gist, if you asking for some thing specific please tell me .

Comment: Maybe related to [THIS](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/2481)